# Facebook oEmbed Video Loading is Choppy

Tags: facebook, drupal-7, oembed

I am using oembed to add a FB video to a webpage.  The users will be adding more in the future.  When the page loads, the video embedding is really choppy.  This doesn’t happen with YouTube or Vimeo videos.  I wanted to know why FB was loading differently than the others and noticed that FB initially downloads a blockquote and some javascript.  Then after the page loads the js connects to FB and replaces the blockquote with an iframe for the video.  The user can see the blockquote being replaced.  It’s not smooth.  YouTube and Vimeo just download the iframe directly.

I’ve already explained to my user that I can’t control how FB responds to my request.  But I wanted to ask if anyone else has seen this and if a workaround exists.